# How do I make the picture on the splash screen come after 1 second

Tags: android, kotlin

I coded splash screen in my project but ı want to splash screen image come 1 second after splash screen starts. Can you create a sample code block about this or provide a source?

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

    if (UiHelper.hasInternetConnection(this)) {
        loadSplashScreen()
    } else {
        UiHelper.customErrorDialog(this, "Connection failed")
    }
}

private fun loadSplashScreen() {
    Handler().postDelayed({
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }, 3000)
}
```

I writed warning messages on componion object. Inside the companion object ui helper class.

Comment: Use animation while loading Splash Activity and set time to load animation

Answer (score 0):

Following the best practice to make a spash screen:

**0. Inside res/drawable folder create a file "launch_screen.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/my_splash_image" /> <---- replace with your spash image
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**1. Insert in your Manifest.xml this line android:theme="@style/AppTheme" like follow and inside first activity:  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.myapp">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">

            <meta-data
                android:name="preloaded_fonts"
                android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**2. Open styles.xml from res/values folder and paste the following:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item> 
    </style>

</resources>
```

And all is done :-)